# How to ensure matrix/array shape when performing slicing and other operations in Python?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have been running into an interesting problem when performing operations on matrices and arrays in python. I'm converting some code from MATLAB to python and this quirk of python is generating a significant amount of bugs in my code.

For example:

say I want perform this operation in python with a Nx1 array

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn 
...
N = 50 
u = np.cumprod(rand(N,1))**(1.0/np.arange(N,0,-1))
```

rather than getting the element wise power of 2 arrays resulting in a vector, I get this massive matrix and this is not the only example,

on inspection I found that for example the shape of `np.arange(..).shape` in this case is `(N,)` a null dimension size, similarly if I slice a matrix eg.

```
X[:,3].shape = (N,)
```

and rather than simply getting two column matrices multiplied together broadcasting assumes I want a matrix when multiplying say `(N,1)*(N,) = (N,N)` when I want `= (N,1)`

how can I perform these operations and ensure their dimensions? i.e. I want to be able top slice a matrix and get a column vector or find the `np.cumprod()` or `np.cumsum()` in one dimension of a matrix and get a vector..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid broadcasting, all the inputs need to match in shape.

Thus giving both parts a single shape, e.g. `(5,)`:

```
np.random.randn(5)**(1.0/np.arange(5,0,-1))
```

produces a result of the same shape:

```
array([        nan,         nan,  0.9643002 ,         nan,  0.55951515])
```

making both `(5,1)` ensures that the output is also `(5,1)`.

```
np.random.randn(5,1)**(1.0/np.arange(5,0,-1).reshape(5,1))
array([[        nan],
       [        nan],
       [ 0.83152719],
       [        nan],
       [ 1.64430971]])
```

A key difference when moving from MATLAB is that there everything has atleast 2 dim.

`np.atleast_2d` might help if you are bothered by 1d arrays. It adds singleton dimensions at the front end as needed.

```
np.atleast_2d(np.arange(5))  # (1,5) array
# array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

`np.array` also has a `ndmin` optional parameter, acting the same way.

```
np.array(np.arange(5),ndmin=2)
```

That raises another difference.  MATLAB prefers to added dimensions at the end.  numpy does this most readily at the beginning.

These all produce the same `(5,5)` array:

```
np.ones((5,1))*np.ones(5)
np.ones((5,1))*np.ones((1,5))
np.ones((5,5))*np.ones((5,5))
```

Octave has added numpy like broadcasting to MATLAB like syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This problem was producing rather weird behavior in my code. For completeness could you include the comments made by @Mr with regards to slicing subtleties then you would have completely answered my question

Answer (score 0):

You are unintentionally broadcasting the results. Change `rand(N,1)` to `rand(N)` and it will work as you expect.

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(4)
>>> b = np.random.rand(4, 1)
>>> c = np.arange(4)
>>> print(a.shape, b.shape)
((4,), (4, 1))
>>> print((a * c).shape, (b * c).shape)
((4,), (4, 4))
>>>
```

In general you can remove unwanted single dimensions with `squeeze`

```
>>> print(b.shape, np.squeeze(b).shape)
((4, 1), (4,))
```

There is also a subtle difference between actual slicing and selection a row/column with indexing:

```
>>> x = np.random.rand(4, 3)
>>> x[:, 1:2].shape # sliicing
(4, 1)
>>> x[:, 2].shape # indexing
(4,)
>>>
```

- http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/numpy.html#broadcasting

Comment: Thanks for the info about the slicing, that's an interesting point. Is there an opposite function to squeeze (I want to ensure that a function returns the single dimension or force it to have one)